# Search and return text from column in Excel

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, wildcard

I have an Excel worksheet and am trying to figure out the formula for the following:

With my formula, I want to search all 700 rows of Column A for cells that contain `aa_product11.12`

Column A's value may or may not contain those values (some will, some will not). And, this is only the partial value. All of the cells have more data, i.e.

```
  Column A
  Sept01_aa_product11.12; 
  Oct01_aa_product11.12;
```

and so forth.

I need the full values of those cells that match, to show up in B1. So, the formula in B1 will search all of column A for `aa_product11.12` and then B1 will look like:

```
 Cell B1
 Sept01_aa_product11.12, Oct01_aa_product11.12, Jan02_aa_product11.12,    
 Aug08_aa_product11.12
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I know Kyle was nice enough to edit my question, but the there is only cell B1 with all of the results, not column B. Thank you!

Comment: Would it be okay to concatenate the cells containing `aa_product11.12` after getting those cells in the first place? Otherwise, I think that a better solution would involve VBA.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a database. Excel wasn't designed for this kind of things...

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/860240-concatall-udf-by-tigeravatar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will not immediately give you the concatenated results, but they are the step(s) before this:

### Without formula:

1. Insert a filter and filter on Text with the criteria 'Contains aa_product11.12'.
2. Copy the column after the filter and paste the results in a fresh sheet.

You can then remove the filter and transfer the results back to the original sheet.

---

### With a formula:

In B1, put the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$700,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("aa_product11.12",$A$1:$A$700)),ROW($A$1:$A$700),9.9E+208),ROW())),"")
```

But this is an array formula which will require using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ to work properly. After this, fill down the formula until there are no more results returned to proceed to the last step.

---

After doing either of these, you can run a `CONCATENATE` on the cells:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,", ",B2,", ", ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, You need to open your Visual Basic Editor and create a module.  Place the following code in your module:

```
Function Get_Data()

Dim Strg As String
Dim Boo As Boolean
    Boo = False
Dim i
    i = 1

For i = i To 65000

Strg = Cells(i, 1).Value

If InStr(1, Strg, "aa_product11.12") Then

    If Boo = True Then
    Get_Data = Get_Data & Cells(i, 1).Value & ", "
    Else
    Get_Data = Cells(i, 1).Value & ", "
    Boo = True
    End If

End If

Next i

End Function
```

Save file as a Macro-Enabled workbook.  Then go to cell B1 and type in:  =Get_Data()

Press enter and the function should work. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you Placet_Auxilium_Me!!